# Fetch and Store Latitude / Longitude API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

Looking into the geocoder gem for Rails, I'm trying to find an API where I can pass an address, get results back that include latitude and longitude, *and* be able to store only the latitude and longitude in my app's database.

Has anyone found a service that allows this?  I know Google has it in their TOS that the data cannot be persisted and must be used with a map.  Bing's TOS almost makes it sound like this is allowed, but it's very grey - and I'm obviously not a lawyer.

Anyone else looked at this and maybe found a solution that would save me some time?

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder docs list all of the providers that the gem supports and lists the services that each provider supports as well as limitations of each.

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#listing-and-comparison

Comment: Right, but these all either a) don't allow storage or b) have question marks next to them.